# How to display dialog only on complete of a successful form submit

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, dialog

I have a form with 2 required input fields and a command button which shows a dialog:

```
<p:commandButton id="showDialogButton" value="Enregistrer" 
    action="#{DEQbean.Ajouter()}" update="@form"
    oncomplete="dialogaboutDEQ.show()" />

<p:dialog id="reamrquesDEQ" widgetVar="dialogaboutDEQ" header="Informations"
    width="400" closable="false" resizable="false" showEffect="clip"
    hideEffect="clip" modal="true" appendToBody="true">

    <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"/>
    <p:commandButton value="OK" action="DEQlist" />    
</p:dialog>
```

I would like to show the dialog only when the validation has passed and the action method is executed. However, when the required input fields are empty and the action method is thus not executed, the dialog is still shown.

How do I display the dialog only on complete of a successful form submit?

Comment: Firstly: Rework your question. It is hard to decipher what you are asking for. You will definitively get more attention if your format everything nicely and try to be as clear as possible. 
However, if I interpreted your question right the 
 answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9195756/332248) might help.

Comment: @Jens: question was already edited 10 minutes before your comment.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that. I started editing the question myself but gave it up when I realized it is not only some English shortcomings. Then I wrote my comment. How do you decide to edit the question yourself and when to ask the OP to do this? I am sure Adriano could have done better than that. And looking at your edit it was not only some "cleanup" of bad english. Where is Adrianos motivation to strive to do better on the next question?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The PrimeFaces ajax response puts an `args` object in the JS scope which has a `validationFailed` property. You could just check for that in the `oncomplete`.

```
<p:commandButton ... oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) dialogaboutDEQ.show()" />
```

If you're performing [validation in action method instead of in a normal validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892225/jsf-2-0-validation-in-actionlistener-or-action-method), and you can't rework that, then you need to manually call [`FacesContext#validationFailed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#validationFailed--).

#### See also:

- [Prevent confirmation dialogue from opening when there's a validation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650817/prevent-confirmation-dialogue-from-opening-when-theres-a-validation-error/15658368#15658368)

---

A different alternative is to use [`RequestContext#execute()`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.5/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29) inside action method to programmatically instruct PrimeFaces to execute the given piece of JS code. So, instead of the `oncomplete`, you could also do this in action method:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("dialogaboutDEQ.show()");
```

If the validation fails, then the action method is not invoked and then this would also not be executed.

#### See also:

- [How to find indication of a Validation error (required="true") while doing ajax command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617914/how-to-find-indication-of-a-validation-error-required-true-while-doing-ajax/9623012#9623012)

---

Again a different alternative is to use the dialog's `visible` attribute. Your command button is apparently updating the whole form including the dialog (even though the dialog is at its own badly declared with `appendToBody="true"` which would cause it to not be inside the parent form anymore; i.e. it must have `appendToBody="false"` or have its own form, but ala). You could check e.g. on [`FacesContext#isPostback()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isPostback%28%29) and [`FacesContext#isValidationFailed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isValidationFailed%28%29) if a successful postback is performed:

```
<p:dialog ... visible="#{facesContext.postback and not facesContext.validationFailed}">
```

#### See also:

- [Difference between rendered and visible attributes of <p:dialog>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050669/difference-between-rendered-and-visible-attributes-of-pdialog/10050924#10050924)
- [How to show a popup in primefaces with the requiredMessages, only if these messages exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797541/how-to-show-a-popup-in-primefaces-with-the-requiredmessages-only-if-these-messa/10801252#10801252)